# How to get a value from a function outside of it JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I ask for help, I do not understand myself whether it is really possible to pull this off, the question is probably stupid for someone. I marked it in the code with comments, I would be grateful if you would give the question a little of your time, thank you.

```
let thelamports = useState(0);/// how to get the value from here connection.getBalance
let theWallet = "9m5kFDqgpf7Ckzbox91RYcADqcmvxW4MmuNvroD5H2r9"
function getWallet(){

    
}

const Content: FC = () => {
    let [lamports, setLamports] = useState(0);
    let [wallet, setWallet] = useState("9m5kFDqgpf7Ckzbox91RYcADqcmvxW4MmuNvroD5H2r9");

  
    

    const { connection } = useConnection();
    const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();

    const onClick = useCallback( async () => {

        if (!publicKey) throw new WalletNotConnectedError();
        connection.getBalance(publicKey).then((bal) => {
            console.log(bal);// the value I need is output to the console, how to send this value to "thelamports"

        });

        console.log(publicKey.toBase58());
        console.log("lamports sending: {}", thelamports)
        const transaction = new Transaction().add(
            SystemProgram.transfer({

                fromPubkey: publicKey,
                toPubkey: new PublicKey(theWallet),
                lamports: thelamports,
            })
        );

        const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);

        await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'processed');
    }, [publicKey, sendTransaction, connection]);
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to do, the comment in the code doesn't make sense (at least to me). The `thelamports` variable contains an integer, how do you expect send anything to it?

Comment: is `bal` variable contains an object? If so and assuming it contains `LAMPORTS_PER_SOL` property, then you can set your `thelamports` variable with: `thelamports = bal.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;`

Comment: the code works without LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, there is no need for this. getBalance is an integer. Thank you for your answers, I apologize for the fact that nothing is clear to you, it is difficult to put the question correctly using google translate(. I edited the code considering your questions

Comment: that's fine, just use `thelamports = bal;` then. But I suspect you are looking for a wrong solution, it seems to me you are trying access data generated in async function, which is requires first understanding how promise (async) works: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: maybe it is. I'm not good at this. Thank you for your reply